# При добавлении узла на страницу происходит ошибка?

Tags: javascript

```js
var date = new Date();
var body = document.body;

body.appendChild(date);
```

```js
var date = new Date();
var body = document.body;
body.innerHTML = date;
```

1. При добавлении узла на страницу через innerHTML не происходит ошибки
2. Я правильно понял что через appendChild и insertBefore можно добавлять html элементы
3. innerHTML добавляет текст с учетом HTML тегов ?

Comment: 1. Да. 2. Да. 3. Да

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov спасибо (какой-то текст ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, `appendChild` принимает именно `element`, а не строку.

```js
const date = Date.now();
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = date;

document.body.appendChild(container);
```